# How to display data related to the items on click in the listview? (onclicklistener)

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, android-studio

I have a listview which gets data from a JSON. So far i was able to show the data in a listview. (here data is list of agents) .
Now I want to open a new activity when a particular agent is clicked in the listview which will display the agent details like name, phone, email etc....

I would appreciate any ideas as I am new to android.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

{

```
private String jsonResult;
public String url = "http://111.111.111.1/androidapp/getjson.php";
ListView listView;
List<Map<String, String>> agents = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    accessWebService();
}
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error ..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        ListDrwaer();
    }
}

public void accessWebService() {
    JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
    task.execute(new String[]{url});
}

public void ListDrwaer() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult.substring(jsonResult.indexOf("{"), jsonResult.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
        JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("agents");

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put("AgtFirstName", c.getString("AgtFirstName"));
            map.put("AgtLastName", c.getString("AgtLastName"));

            MyArrList.add(map);

            SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
            simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, MyArrList, R.layout.activity_column, new String[]{"AgtFirstName", "AgtLastName"}, new int[]{R.id.AgtFirstName , R.id.AgtLastName});

            listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error parsing..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

          if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AgentDetails.class);
        i.putExtra("position", map.get(position));
        startActivity(i);

    }
};
```

}

Comment: Simply you can get data onitem click and send via intent

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N  I did use onItemClick but the data is not displaying in the other activity

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options you could utilise.

1) to set OnItemClick which will trigger of any component in the respective ListView entry (position indicates which specific item entry has been selected) (OnItemLongClick could also be used in a similar way).

or

2) to set OnClick Listener for specific views within a ListView. This Allow specific actions different elements/views within a Listview entry.

For example I have a ListView that contains a number of TextViews, two of which I want to take actions (mark as done and delete)as if the Textviews were buttons. With these I set onClick's in the XML. problem with this is you don't know which entry (ie no position, solution use setTags). I also have OnItemClick. So clicking elsewhere allows other options/actions.

Code for 1 (other actions) where **shoppinglistlv** is the ListView (Note how position is available), this is in the onCreate method:-

```
shoppinglistlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "ListView clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

For 2 I have:-

```
public void sledelete(View view) {
        Integer tag = (Integer)view.getTag();
        shoppinglistcsr.moveToPosition(tag);
        shopperdb.setShopListEntryAsComplete(shoppinglistcsr.getLong(0));
        shoppinglistcsr = shopperdb.getShoppingList();
        currentsla.swapCursor(shoppinglistcsr);
    }
public void slareorg(View view) {
        shopperdb.reorgShopList();
        shoppinglistcsr = shopperdb.getShoppingList();
        currentsla.swapCursor(shoppinglistcsr);
    }
```

Along with (Note onClick's that result in above methods being called, setTag is done in the bindView of the adapter). This is from the XML for the ListView Entry rather than the ListView itself:-

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shoppinglist_donebutton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_subsubsubheading_height"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/standarddonebutton"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/standard_subsubsubheading_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@color/colorNormalButton"
            android:textColor="@color/colorNormalButtonText"
            android:onClick="sledone"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.005"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/shoppinglist_deletebutton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/standard_dummy_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_subsubsubheading_height"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/standarddeletetext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/standard_subsubsubheading_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@color/colorRequiredLabel"
            android:textColor="@color/colorNormalButtonText"
            android:onClick="sledelete"/>
```

Along with this in the adpater's bindView  (set's tag to position) Note donebtntv and deletebtntv holding the respective Textview id's:-

```
// Set tags to enable onClick to determine the cursor position of the clicked entry
donebtntv.setTag(Integer.valueOf(pos));
deletebtntv.setTag(Integer.valueOf(pos));
```

Lastly, in the ListView's XML root I also have :-

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

(I'm not sure if this is required, however I do get both types, 1 & 2 above, handled with this)

This is perhaps overly complex, but shows you some options.

Here's some more example code for OnItemClick that starts other activities, dependent upon dialog selection. This shows how you can pass data via intent extras:-

```
// Click on an Aisle to update the Aisle or Stock the Aisle
        aisleslistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.aalbclv01);
        aisleslistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                AlertDialog.Builder okdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                okdialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.aislelistclicktitle));
                okdialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.aislelistclicktext001));
                okdialog.setCancelable(true);
                okdialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.standardedittext), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        resume_state = RESUMESTATE_AISLEUPDATE;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(findViewById(R.id.aalbclv01).getContext(), AisleAddActivity.class);
                        AislesCursorAdapter aisleadapter = (AislesCursorAdapter) ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.aalbclv01)).getAdapter();
                        intent.putExtra("Caller", THIS_ACTIVITY + "Update");
                        intent.putExtra("AisleID", aisleadapter.getCursor().getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ID_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AISLEID", aisleadapter.getCursor().getLong(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ID_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AisleName", aisleadapter.getCursor().getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AisleOrder", aisleadapter.getCursor().getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ORDER_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AisleShopRef", aisleadapter.getCursor().getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_SHOP_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("SHOPID", aisleadapter.getCursor().getLong(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_SHOP_INDEX));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                okdialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.standardstockaisletext), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        resume_state = RESUMESTATE_AISLESTOCK;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(findViewById(R.id.aalbclv01).getContext(), AddProductToShopActivity.class);
                        AislesCursorAdapter aisleadapter = (AislesCursorAdapter) ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.aalbclv01)).getAdapter();
                        intent.putExtra("Caller", THIS_ACTIVITY + "Stock");
                        intent.putExtra("AisleID", aisleadapter.getCursor().getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ID_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AISLEID", aisleadapter.getCursor().getLong(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ID_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AisleName", aisleadapter.getCursor().getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AisleOrder", aisleadapter.getCursor().getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_ORDER_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AisleShopRef", aisleadapter.getCursor().getString(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_SHOP_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("AISLESHOPREF", aisleadapter.getCursor().getLong(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_SHOP_INDEX));
                        intent.putExtra("SHOPID",aisleadapter.getCursor().getLong(ShopperDBHelper.AISLES_COLUMN_SHOP_INDEX));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                okdialog.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.standardbacktext), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        resume_state = RESUMESTATE_NOTHING;
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                okdialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Note! that the above is using SQlite/ Cursors as the list source data. However, the techniques should be similar.

Comment: Thanks Mike I am fetching data from mySQL so how does it work there? I read several tutorials but they are not working for me.. Can you please be specific?

Comment: @Poovizhirajan.N I've not used MySQL data via JSON. However, it looks as though you would used position to get the respective arraylist entry/member and then use map.get("AgtFirstName") etc. Thus you could have, something along the lines of map = MyArrList(position) followed by intent.putExtra("FirstName",map.get("AgtFirstName")); before the startActivity and then have the respective intent extra retrieval in the called activity. e.g. String firstname = getIntent().getStringExtra("FirstName")